# Certificate problems after updating to version Bouncycastle Version 1.56

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, public-key

we have Updated our Bouncycastle Version from 1.55 to 1.56. After this we have trouble with one of our Certificates. Does anybody now why this Problem occurs?

```
caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid info structure in RSA public key                                    
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPublicKey.populateFromPublicKeyInfo(Unknown Source)               
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPublicKey.<init>(Unknown Source)                                  
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.generatePublic(Unknown Source)                            
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)                                        
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.x509.X509CertificateObject.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)                     
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)                          
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1456)`
```

**(UPDATED)**

The problem occurs when loading the KeyStore with the provider Bouncycastle.

```
  keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        keyStore.load(inputStream, "test".toCharArray());
```

Tested things:

ReImport of the Certificate with KeyStoreExplorer 5.3.0 -> Same Problem, 5.1.1 -> Succesfully imported

Is there any new Validation for the RSA Public Key?

Comment: Please post the code that throws this exception.

Comment: Try to export the certificate and re-import it using openssl.or KeystoreExplorer

Comment: I tested the reimport through KeystoreExplorer but the result is the Same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem was that Bouncycastle 1.56 uses Java 8 and therefore no longer accepts certificates with less than 1024 keysize.